# slicing vs html/css

Tags: slices, html

I develop sites in different CMS, wordpress, magento etc. I wanted to know, if slicing is more easy than creating everything in child theme, as there are a lot of margins, and padding involved, and peope like to see a website in pixel perfect.So isn't slicing much more convenient than writing whole css/html? I prefer the latter, as i am much flexible writing css, but too much padding and measurement gets out of hand.How do one coupe of with ever margin and spacing? or should one for slicing? I don't know much about slicing. 

[image: Calculating margins and padding]

Comment: Slicing is a 1990s web building technique. It's pretty much deprecated and should **rarely** be used. Using CSS is a much more elegant manner of building web content.

Answer (score 1):

"Slicing" treats the web page as a pixel-perfect static canvas, which it never has been, nor never will be. It was a bad idea in the 90s and is now an antiquated idea. For just one example, there's simply no way for Photoshop to slice out a responsive web page layout.

So, yes, always work in the actual medium you are designing in whenever you can. In the case of designing a web page, you need to understand (or work with someone that does) the HTML CSS and JS that goes into making the visual presentation.

EDIT:

If, on the other hand, you're asking how to design a web site based on a PSD file in general...

Ideal answer: Don't. PhotoShop is not a web page. While you can certainly give a nice look and feel to a site with the tool, it simply can't be used as a web site design tool as it's a static, fixed canvas. Sites designed solely in PhotoShop tend to be bloated, inflexible, and slow.

At best, the PSD should be used merely as a sketch.

Realistic answer: I do realize that is still how a lot of web sites get built. Visual designers work in a visual tool, then toss that file over the fence to let the developers deal with it. This is a rather antiquated an inefficient way to go about it, but it's not uncommon.

In that situation, I do empathize with you as now the burden is on you to deal with things. I think the best you can do is:

- Try to communicate to the designer that you will do your best to interpret the PSD file, but note that there are always going to have to be slight changes in the process to accommodate the realities of the presentation layer code and browsers and users and devices and the CMS so that the final output may not match pixel-for-pixel
- Save out a flat version of the PSD and then use that as your template. Try to replicate as much of the PSD as you can via CSS (background colors, all content/fonts, etc) and then, as needed, cut-and-paste out the individual elements needed as images.
- If at all possible, integrate the designer with the front end development process. Have them work with you to adjust things as you go. You may find something works better in code and they'll be willing to change. Maybe they'll see it actually working in code and have a better way to implement their idea. Try to make it a collaboration if you can.

Good luck!

Comment: I have asked the OT to rephrase: what s/he wants to know is basically how to create a WP site based on a photoshop image. Without slicing.

Comment: @boblet yes, good point. I expanded my answer in hopes it addresses that angle as well.

Comment: How does someone design a site if Photoshop shouldn't be used? This is where I get confused...

Comment: @OghmaOsiris it's not that Photoshop shouldn't be used at all, but rather HOW it should be used. Ideally PhotoShop is a place for sketching...to communicate the visuals needed to validate the design. But the actual building of the design should be done with the presentation layer in mind. These days, a lot of designers (myself included) start in code, and use PhotoShop as needed to create the images needed to accentuate the design that's in code.

Answer (score 0):

Make child themes in WP. The changes you make in your child theme are only overrides of what you want to change. You will have far more control and flexibility. You can group overrides in your child theme, and margin and padding should be easily solved that way.

Comment: It becoming time consuming as i am not power user of PS, don't know how to take out margins and padding of elements expect the measurement tool.

Comment: I do not understand why you want to mix photoshop into the WP themes at all?

Comment: I have psd's, so of course i have to assess the measurement and cut out images, like banner, header etc.Like the example i posted. So how do i keep track of measurement between elements.

Comment: By "slicing" you mean to take a complete psd document that shows an _entire_ website, and cut it _whithout_ actually removing whitespace? Or do you take a psd document and extract only the parts you need?

Comment: the latter one.

Comment: I do not think I understand what you are asking? You have a bunch of different images, that put together _does not_ add up to an entire web page. So you use html&css to place these within divs. And your major problem is consistent margin and padding? Why would it help to slice psd files differently? How would that help?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11916/discussion-between-nofel-and-boblet)

Comment: Yes, exctracting only the elements you need isn't what most people traditionally call 'slicing'. Slicing usually refers to the use of a static design tool (PhotoShop, Fireworks, etc.) and then having that tool cut up the image and create all the HTML and CSS for you in the process. This usually results in an unholy mess of uneditable code.